# Centralized logging system for multiple azure functions?

Tags: azure, logging, azure-functions, azure-application-insights, centralized

I have many azure functions. I want to store logs of every azure function at one single location. I first stored all logs in azure append blob. But now I want to store and visualize in real time. I found some solution like [loggly.com](https://www.loggly.com) for centralized solution. 
Is there any solution in azure?
  If yes, what is it?
  If no, what is other options do I have?

Comment: Have you tried Azure Application Insights?

Comment: Yes. But it is separate for each azure function. I want only one logging system for all azure functions. For example I have tried using append blob to append all logs coming from different azure functions in a single file.



I have one more need.
Can I send custom logs to app insights? Like I want to send logs like azure function 1,started, time, GUID, filename, containername, etc. This will be one row of logs

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should create an Application Insights resource. Then use the same instrumentation key to all your Azure Functions. Here's a step by step how to do it:

https://medium.com/@WorkloadRancher/step-by-step-add-application-insights-to-azure-function-http-triggers-8d10d19c21fc

Comment: Can I send custom logs to app insights? Like I want to send logs like azure function 1,started, time, GUID, filename, containername, etc. This will be one row of logs.
Basically I want to store my logs in table view in application insights and query them.

Comment: absolutely. all messages logged using ILogger will be transfered to Application Insights.